# Generar div con bucle for en función a tantas posiciones de un ArrayList

Tags: java, bucle-for, div, hashmap

Tengo un objeto `HashMap` que contiene un `ArrayList` con 12 posiciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo una vista `FTL` para generar `div` con bucle `for` en función a la longitud de este ArrayList, es decir, que si me llegan 12 posiciones me genere 12 `div`, si me llegan 5 posiciones que me genere 5 `div`.

De que manera puedo implementar este bucle for?

Comment: Bien, ¿y la duda es?

Comment: @JDev no se como implementar este bucle for en la vista ftl para generar los div en función al ArrayList.

Comment: El elemanto `<#list>` te sirve para eso.